# How can I create a cycles node setup for this black hole

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

so I am making a black hole in blender. I am "following" a tutorial for it, but it isn't exactly made for blender, but lightwave 3d. Now I am trying to create an innersteller like black hole, with the acceleration disk, and the gravitational lenses, and there are ways to do it, but I am not as experienced as you guys are in the node editor. I've been looking all over the web for ways to do it, but to no avail, so, please help a friend out.

Here is the video I am following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxyKKKTD6Qc
I have the models done, and I have HDRi map as a background right now.
[image]

Yes, each object is seperate. If follow along with his video, you will see that he uses refraction and transparency. There isn't that kind of setting readily available to access that I can see right now, and when I comes to shaders and nodes I am lost.
Not exactly meaning to ask for a tutorial, but if someone would be kind enough to layout the nodes that I would need for all three objects, that would be FANTASTIC.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18703/creating-a-black-hole-in-blender

Comment: yes, but that doesn't cover the acceleration disk as seen on tv.