# how to make the background distorted behind an object

Tags: distort

so I'm creating a black hole in Blender 2.8 and am trying to distort the stars (around the blue circle in the screenshot) in the background behind the black hole. Unfortunately, I am having trouble applying this effect in the node editor. Does anyone know how to make this distortion effect like the one on this picture ([blackhole pic](http://w4.wallls.com/uploads/high-thumbnail/201711/29/179920.jpg))???

I have attached a link to the file [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah2aL3r7RO3T00b1q5mPDSkjQOZ4) along with a couple of screenshots of my project down below.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: I'm sure that would be done with a **lightpath** node, unfortunately I know very little about it, except that it is often used for this type of effect.

Comment: The big gandalf3, lord of the black ring, has done it https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18703/creating-a-black-hole-in-blender/23574#23574