# How to use the array function

Tags: modifiers

Apologies if this has been asked before but I cannot find anything that answers my question. I'm trying to use an array with an empty offset by 2 degrees. The idea is to create multiple planes rotated around the Z axis. However, when I set the array up it just creates 4 planes 2 degrees from each other. I want 46 planes rotating around to create a quarter circle. I have uploaded the file, so hopefully, it will show the problem far better than I can explain it.

Dave

[image]

Comment: You should [edit your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/165795/edit)  and add at least one or two images so that other users do not have to rely on a file to understand your question.

Comment: How do I add images, please?  I cannot find any way to upload images.

Comment: Use the built in tools above the body of your post when editing. See [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2MDT.png) for example, the image upload is outlined in red.

Comment: Thanks Tima, I don't now why I couldn't find it before.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you want to do is to have a starting object that is more than just a line. The array modifier will take your object and duplicate it with some offset. Thus, what you would've ended up with (in the case that the array was setup properly), would be 48 lines without any planes.

Add a *Mesh > Circle* with 48*4 = 192 vertices. Then, select all of the circle's vertices except for two adjacent ones (that you want to keep) in *Edit Mode*, press <kbd>ALt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge at Center*. This will create the center vertex. Join the two perimeter vertices by selecting them and pressing <kbd>F</kbd>, then select everything with <kbd>A</kbd>, and press <kbd>F</kbd> again to fill in the triangle.

Then, add in the *Array* modifier to the triangle. Disable the *Relative Offset*, and enable the *Object Offset* as you did in your attached file. Add the *Empty Axis*, and rotate it in the Z-axis by 90/48 = 1.875 degrees.

Use the empty for the *Object Offset* in the *Array* modifier, and you've now gotten a quarter circle made up of 48 triangles.

[image]

**Edit:**

From your blend file, the reason why your array isn't working properly is that you have an unapplied rotation to the "Circle" object. Select the circle object and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select *Apply > Rotation*. Your array works fine after that step.

Comment: I'm trying to follow this tutorial https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18703/creating-a-black-hole-in-blender. You'll need to scroll down just under half way to see the part that I'm trying to copy. But when I add the array and empty as shown in the tutorial, I get this weird shape, that bears no resemblance to what is being shown in the tutorial. I would add a picture, but don't know how.

Comment: @Dave you can edit your question and insert the image into there.

Comment: @Dave found your problem, added it into my solution

Comment: Thanks for your help. I now have it working.