# Change the angle of an area light?

Tags: lighting

Is there a possibility to change the angle between the direction of an area light and the area in Blender? To angle the entire area light won't work for what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: You mean Bending the light? Does this answer your question? [Creating a Black Hole in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18703/creating-a-black-hole-in-blender)

Comment: What do your mean by "angle the entire area", by that do you mean angle of 90 degrees?  Why won't that work -- express your goal so that you'll get more focused help, faster.

Comment: I think what you may want is a Spot light, not an Area light, if you want to control the spread-out angle.

Comment: You can scale the area light

Comment: I am trying to build a window that simulates daylight coming through a window, without actual light coming through a window. The program used to render the scene (Mitsuba) has an issue with light coming through objects, so I am trying to find a way arount that. Deleting the glass of the window is sadly also not an option, as the goal is to create an as close as possible to realistic room. So the idea was to use an area light and scale it to the size of the window and put it directly in front of the window, on the inside of the room. But the light travelling parallel to the floor looks

Comment: very unrealistic why I'd like to change the angle.